# Split string into array then loop into HTML table

Tags: php, loops

I have a string extracted from a database in the example below. I'm trying to loop through the string into a HTML table to display the results as in the diagram. The string can vary in length but will always follow the same format.

```
$string = "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68"

_______________________________________________________________________
              |18/05-01/06  | 01/06-06/07 | 06/07-22/08 | 22/08-14/09 |
_______________________________________________________________________
DR Record + 2 | 21.47       | 20.24       | 27.15       | 20.24       |
_______________________________________________________________________
BE Record + 2 | 24.05       | 22.68       |             |             |
_______________________________________________________________________
```

Everything i've tried doesn't seem to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is what i've tried so far

```
$string = "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68"

$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $string );

$date = array();
$record = array();
$price = array();

foreach($parts as $part) {
    // check date
    if(strpos($part,'-') !== false) {
        $date[] = $part;
    }
    // check price
    elseif(strpos($part, '+') !== false) {
        $record[] = $part;
    }
    // echeck record
    elseif(strpos($part, '.') !== false) { 
        $price[] = $part;
    } 
}
```

Comment: And your approach is ..?

Comment: Please show some code of what you've attempted.  Also, do you have any control over the string extracted from the database?  It'd be nice to have different separators for the columns and rows.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo i've updated my answer with my latest failed attempt

Comment: @CMKanode i've updated my answer with my latest failed attempt

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $string ); //it returns an array
```

Comment: Thanks shuvo. I tried this but i was difficult to bind them where required afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function gsb($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini    = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$s= "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68";
$s1=explode(" ",gsb("*".$s,"*"," DR"));//'*' is just used to add an char at first so that we can extract string between it.
$dr=explode(" ",gsb($s," DR Record "," BE Record"));
$be=explode(" ",gsb($s.'*',$dr[count($dr)-2].' '.$dr[count($dr)-1].' ',"*"));//Edited according to comment and you need to access values from $be[2] as $be[0]$$be[1] will contain those two words.
?>
```

Now you have 3 arrays `$s1`,`$dr`& `$be` containing all the values of table you need now just use it according to your requirments.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that the `BE Record` could be any two letters not just `BE`

Comment: Edited my answer according to your comment

Comment: You need to use two array elements $dr[0] & $dr[1] to get +2

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run the code but the arrays are mixed up PHPFIDDLE http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fwq-97n

Comment: That occurred because value 20.24 was repeated but now i have updated my code now hopefully it wont occur again.

Comment: But still as of now you need to get + and 2 from two array variable and $be[0]$$be[1] will contain those two words if you can handle this then its ok else tell me and i will update it for you